# What is the command in Awesome Window manager to let go of a key that has not been let go of?

Tags: window-manager, awesome, lua

My <kbd>v</kbd> key is locked up after I use the below snippet in my `rc.lua` file.

#### Background

Hotkey combinations are usually all pressed together at the same time.

I am using the function key <kbd>Fn</kbd> which works as a key chain only because of the way it works with the firmware on my ThinkPad.

Key chain means you press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, release it, then press another key.

In other words, key chain keys are not pressed together but sequentially, one after the other.

#### Setup

My <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is `XF86WakeUp`.

The following below is part of my `rc.lua`

```
-- open edit ".vimrc"

awful.key({ "XF86WakeUp" }, "v", function ()

awful.util.spawn("termite -e 'nvim /home/Dropbox/.vimrc'") end,

{description = "Edit .vimrc", group = "Code"}),
```

This snippet works just fine; I press <kbd>Fn</kbd>, release it, then press <kbd>v</kbd> and vim opens.

Just as intended.

#### Problem

After I have used this keychain, Awesome will not let go of the <kbd>v</kbd> key and every time after that when I press the <kbd>v</kbd> key, for whatever reason, vim opens.

This is less than ideal.

How to stop this behavior in Awesome?